# String replace adventure in Java

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I'm trying to achieve this - If a string contains the pattern `%25` followed by any number of alpha-numeric characters, then i need to replace `%25` with `%`. The following code doesn't seem to be right-

```
while (userPassword.contains("%25"+"[^A-Za-z0-9]*")) {
    userPassword = userPassword.replace("%25", "%");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `String.contains()` does not work with regular expressions, but with simple texts, so you are actually looking at the *exact* sequence "%25[^A-Za-z0-9]" in your string. Also, `^` means that it should match what is NOT in the character class, that is no alphanumeric character, and this is the opposite of what you want.

You can instead use the method `String.matches`:

```
while (userPassword.matches(".*%25[A-Za-z0-9]*"))
```

(As you see, I put all the regular expression in a single string. The compiler would have done that for you, but it's more clear)

For example:

```
String userPassword = "%25sdflk42"; 

System.out.println(userPassword.contains("%25"+"[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
System.out.println(userPassword.matches(".*%25[A-Za-z0-9]*"));
```

This will print:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful here. [`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) does ***not*** interpret the argument as regex.

Try this:

```
userPassword = userPassword.replaceAll("%25([a-zA-Z0-9]*)", "%$1");
```

Which uses back-referencing to replace only a part of the captured pattern. From the documentation:

> Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (userPassword.contains("%25"+"[^A-Za-z0-9]*"))
```

should be

```
while (userPassword.contains("%25"+"[A-Za-z0-9]*"))
```

Comment: you could also make all of this into a single string

Comment: This also doesn't work, because `contains` doesn't take a regex.